# Is adding variables to a multiple regression Model always "Hierachical Regression"?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I want to test the connection between N,G and the Interaction of NxG to Y for an assignment. My task is to first do an multiple Regression with N+G and then integrate the interaction of both in a second Model. Would this be considered "Hierachical Regression" or is this just testing multiple Models and more "usual multiple Regression"? I don't know how to separate the two concepts. I dont try to find the best Model btw.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Short answer: no. For a good, clear intro to hierarchical modeling read Singer's paper, *Using SAS PROC MIXED to Fit Multilevel Models* https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.3102/10769986023004323  Ignore the SAS part, to my knowledge it's simply one of the best written reviews of the subject.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Mixed models are the other meaning of hierarchical regression. This is not what you want.

Comment: Imo the conflation of terms is illustrative of a shortfall or weakness in colloquial statistical understanding, one I wasn't aware of until now. *Hierarchical regression*, as defined, cannot be taken literally since it involves nothing more than entering variables sequentially, whether automated or by hand, into a regression model. Where's the theory in this? It loses nothing in meaning if described as *heterarchical regression*. Whereas, mixed, multi-level, hierarchical models are explicitly theoretical in derivation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why it matters, but .... Yes, the term is certainly used that way. I've seen it in many papers, and also in places such as [Analysis Factor](https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/confusing-statistical-term-4-hierarchical-regression-vs-hierarchical-model/), [Springer](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-6351-086-8_10) (the article is behind a paywall, but the abstract is clear), and [UVA](https://library.virginia.edu/data/articles/hierarchical-linear-regression).

Be careful not to confuse hierarchical regression with hierarchical linear models.